# Analog clock made out javascript/html/css not working

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am a beginner in html/css/javascript. I want to create a clock and I have the code over here. However, this code is not working so I suppose that I have an error somewhere.

Can someone please find the error and tell me how to fix it.

***CSS***

```js
function clock() {
  var d, h, m, s;

  h = 30 * ((d.getHours() % 12) + d.getMinutes() / 60);
  m = 6 * d.getMinutes();
  s = 6 * d.getSeconds();

  setAttr('h-hand', h);
  setAttr('m-hand', m);
  setAttr('s-hand', s);
  setAttr('s-tail', s + 180);

  h = d.getHours();
  m = d.getMinutes();
  s = d.getSeconds();

  if (h >= 12) {
    setText('suffix', 'PM');
  } else {
    setText('suffix', 'AM');
  }

  if (h != 12) {
    h %= 12;
  }
};

function setAttr(id, val) {
  var v = 'rotate(' + val + ', 70, 70)';
  document.getElementById(id).setAttribute('transform', v);
};

function setText(id, val) {
  if (val < 10) {
    val = '0' + val;
  }
  document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = val;
};
```

```css
#analog-clock {
  width: 140px;
  height: 140px;
}
#clock-face {
  stroke: black;
  fill: #ff9933;
}
#h-hand,
#m-hand,
#s-hand,
#s-tail {
  stroke: black;
  stroke-linecap: round;
}
#h-hand {
  stroke-width: 3px;
}
#m-hand {
  stroke-width: 2px;
}
#s-hand {
  stroke-width: 1px;
}
```

```html
<div class="analog-clock">
  <svg width="140" height="140">
    <circle id="clock-face" cx="70" cy="70" r="65" />
    <line id="h-hand" x1="70" y1="70" x2="70" y2="38" />
    <line id="m-hand" x1="70" y1="70" x2="70" y2="20" />
    <line id="s-hand" x1="70" y1="70" x2="70" y2="12" />
    <line id="s-tail" x1="70" y1="70" x2="70" y2="56" />
    <text x="62" y="18">12</text>
    <text x="126" y="76">3</text>
    <text x="66" y="130">6</text>
    <text x="7" y="76">9</text>
  </svg>
  <div style="height: 10px;"></div>
  <div class="time-text">
    <span id="hr" style="color: #4d0099;">00</span>
    <span style="color: black;">:</span>
    <span id="min" style="color: #006633;">00</span>
    <span style="color: black;">:</span>
    <span style="color: #990000;" id="sec">00</span>
    <span id="suffix">--</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What exactly is your question? You CSS fails? Your Javascript is failing silently? You want help debugging the problem? You not sure how to reduce the problem to the smallest, complete code to allow others to help you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to initialize the `d` variable with current Date. Also you can put the `clock()` call in the `setInterval` function to update your clock every second. Not sure if this is a best solution, but at least it works.

Example: http://jsbin.com/cegutilavo/edit?js,console,output

Lines 3 and 40.

Comment: Ok, I added the lines which i didn't have, and my clock is working.

Answer (score 4):

You have you `d` variable undefined.

declare it

```
var d = new Date(),
        h, m, s;
```

and it will work. Working clock [here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZOPqBx).

Comment: It seems that your codepen is not working. I added var d = new Date();, but my code is still not working.

Comment: `var d = new Date();, ` is wrong - I edited answer to show you full string right in the beginning of function where all variable are declared

Comment: and yes, you have to start the clock by calling `clock();` - it's also in my pen

Comment: The clock is at its right position, but it is still not moving. However, this improved the result, so +1 upvote.

Comment: Now it's moving and I played with the skin also to make it cooler )

Comment: The design is nice, I will do something like that to modify my clock.